# Roots of equation $x^2+kx+p=0$ are $2$ distinct positive integer, Then $k+p$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $k$ be an integer and $p$ be a prime number such that  equation $x^2+kx+p=0$ has $2$
>
> distinct positive integer solution,Then $k+p=$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Given $$\displaystyle x^2+kx+p=0\Rightarrow x = \frac{-k\pm \sqrt{k^2-4p}}{2}$$

Now if $x\in \mathbb{Z}\;,$ Then $k^2-4p=l^2\;,$ Where $l\in \mathbb{Z}$

So We get $k^2-l^2 = 4p\Rightarrow (k-l)(k+l) = 4p$

Now I did not understand how can I solve after that, Help me

Thanks

Comment: By the rational roots theorem, the solutions are $1$ and $p$. Their sum is $-k$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Why not -1 or -p?

Comment: @wythagoras:  Because the problem says positive solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: You can avoid using the quadratic formula. Instead use this fact if it has two integer solutions $a$, $b$ then $x^2+kx+p=(x-a)(x-b)$. Multiply out and you should get two sepearate equations to work with.

Answer (score 2):

If the integer roots are $r_1$ and $r_2$ then 
$$x^2+kx+p=(x-r_1)(x-r_2)=x^2+(-r_2-r_1)x+r_1r_2 $$
Equating coefficients $k=-r_1-r_2, \; \; p=r_1r_2$, since $p$ is prime and the roots are positive assume $r_1=1$ and $r_2=p$, 
$$k+p=-p+p-1=-1$$

---

Alternately if you know the Rational Root Theorem and Vieta's Formula you can arrive at the answer faster as André Nicolas describes.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the most efficient way, but one can push things through from your discriminant approach. Note that since the roots are positive, $k$ is negative.  We can assume $l\ge 0$.  From your discriminant calculation, we have 
$$(k-l)(k+l)=4p.$$
Since $k-l$ is negative, and $k+l$ and $k-l$ are of the same parity, we have $k+l=-2$ and $k-l=-2p$. Thus $k=-p-1$.